# PHP String - Escape Single Quotes (for jQgrid Select Box)

Tags: php, jqgrid

I have a string:

```
$departmentList = "value:'16:NAR,JR'S OFFICE;17:MFR'S OFFICE;18:NAR/MFR JOINT OFFICE'"
```

My problem is, the single quotes you can see in `JR'S OFFICE` and `MFR's OFFICE` are prematurely ending my string. I could switch my double quotes with single quotes and vice versa, but these are coming from user-entered values. If the user had entered a double quote, I would be in the same boat as I am now.

Any ideas on how to keep the integrity of this string while having single and double quotes throughout?

By the way, not sure if this matters for anything but - I'm putting my $departmentList string into a jQGrid to build the values for a select box.

Comment: Where are you getting the values from? The database? A form? Because on your example, the single quotes aren't a problem.

Comment: More importantly, how is that string going to be used. In which context will it end up. If you are using it as JS string (which you should have told in oyur question), then [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) would be the appropriate escape function. Don't just wrap it in single or double quotes yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to replace `"` with `\"` and `'` with `\'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the input for database purpose better use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

```
$departmentList = "value:'16:NAR,JR'S OFFICE;17:MFR'S OFFICE;18:NAR/MFR JOINT OFFICE'";
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($departmentList);
```

Comment: True, however my string was already built from a SELECT statement. I'm just using this string in javascript. Thanks for the tip though!